# Median Filtering

Tags: r, filter, median

I have below mentioned dataset and I am using "runmed" function to smooth it using median filtering. I can plot using runmed but cant see the resultant values of the function as I want to use the result later. As runmed is meant for scattered plot smoothing only, is there any other way to get a result of median filtering that can be saved to other vector for further processing ? Thanks

```
   runmed(x, k, endrule = c("median", "keep", "constant"),
   algorithm = NULL, print.level = 0)

 [1] 5.010650 5.010634 5.010668 5.010663 5.010671 5.010672 5.010674 5.010672 5.010676 5.010679 5.010681
 [12] 5.010687 5.010695 5.010705 5.010730 5.010716 5.010740 5.010751 5.010764 5.010771 5.010779 5.010777
 [23] 5.010775 5.010775 5.010780 5.010777 5.010777 5.010777 5.010783 5.010800 5.010810 5.010816 5.010828
 [34] 5.010835 5.010840 5.010838 5.010838 5.010837 5.010842 5.010842 5.010840 5.010842
```

Comment: You can save smoothed values directly as `smoothed <-runmed(x, 5)`. `runmed` can be used outside of `plot` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.